# How what does the view look like for act_as_votable? New to rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to have users like an object so I loaded the act_as_votable gem. What does the view look like for the like button?

Answer (score 0):

You may define a link_to button for like as, e.g, your model is Medium

```
<%= link_to 'Like', medium_like_path(@medium) %>
```

and then define your controller action as,

```
 def like
  media = Medium.find(params[:medium_id])
  media.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to :back, notice: 'Liked!'
 end
```